# Physical Asset Management for Medium Sized School

Tags: inventory

I'm looking for recommendations for a physical asset management solution for a medium sized school to keep track of computers, projectors, smart boards, etc.

Musts:

Barcoding/scanning (typing in serial numbers is horrible, especially during a full audit with 1000 pieces of equipment in a hundred different rooms)

Would like:

- Be cloud based (+1 if it can connect to our google apps for education domain)
- Have check in/check out ability
- Track by funding source (schools get money from so many different places and everyone wants very specific information about what their money was used for)

Our situation:
Medium sized school - 70 staff, 850 students, ~1000 pieces of equipment, 1 IT guy.  We may go 1-to-1 in the next few years so the software needs to be quick and easy enough for me to setup and use.

Thanks for any thoughts, let me know if any additional info would be helpful.